# How to include jsp file from another project to current project

Tags: jsp

I want to include header.jsp page from CMS52 project to Services_IVR.index.jsp file
I used following method but it is showing exception. Kindly help me how to include jsp file from another object.

after this I got exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: File "/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/webapps/CMS52/header.jsp" not found
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:522)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: File "/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.56/webapps/CMS52/header.jsp" not found
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:319)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    org.apache.jsp.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:55)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you please review [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with some code and a description of the problem

Comment: I edited my question. Kindly go through it.

Comment: Although Quintin is right regarding your question, the obvious reason for the exception is that the `page` attribute of the `<jsp:include>` tag expects **relative URL** of a page to include, not an absolute path on the file system. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14763794/3511123 for more information.

Comment: Please, refer to the first part of the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096888/sharing-static-resources-between-maven-modules/58177806#answer-58177806