# Maven - Copy resources from module to parent

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I'm trying when I execute mvn package from the parent, the resources files that are in child module, will be copy to a specific directory of the parent module.

Structure of the project:

```
-Parent 
   --ModuleResources
```

Example:

```
ModuleResources 
     src/main/resources/
         package1.file.xml
         package2.file2.jsp
         package3.file3.properties
ParentModule
    src/main/parentResources/  < I want copy resources here.
```

I am newbie working with maven.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check this post: [Sharing static resources between maven modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096888/sharing-static-resources-between-maven-modules)?

Comment: Why would you do that? This seems like a candidate for redesing. How about a third module with the resources which the parent and the child would depend on? That's how we use it. But you may have your reasons.